# Merging dask partitions into one file when writing to s3 Bucket in AWS

Tags: amazon-s3, dask

I've managed to write an oracle database table to an s3 bucket in AWS in parquet format using Dask. However, I was hoping to have a single file written out like in Pandas. I know Dask partitions the data which creates separate files and a folder. I've tried setting append to true and the number of partitions to false but it doesn't make a difference. **Is there a way to merge/append the partitions while writing to an s3 Bucket to create a single parquet file without the folder?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this functionality does not exist currently within Dask. It probably is not too hard to leverage pyarrow or fastparquet to do the work, though, taking the partitions and streaming them into whatever new chunking scheme you like.

I am not sure, but it may be possible to use s3 copy functionality to selectively chop out bytes chunks from the data files and paste into the master file you want to make... This would be far more involve.